# C++ cannot find class within the same namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

Update: The minimal code to reproduce the error:
In TypeTraits.hpp:

```
namespace fl
{
    namespace utilities
    {
        template <class T>
        struct remove_reference
        {
            using type = T;
        };

        template <class T>
        struct remove_reference<T&>
        {
            using type = T;
        };

        template <class T>
        struct remove_reference<T&&>
        {
            using type = T;
        };
    }
}
```

In TypeTraits.h

```
#include "TypeTraits.hpp"
namespace ftd
{
    template <class T> using remove_reference = fl::utilities::remove_reference<T>;
}
```

In Utility.h:

```
#include "TypeTraits.h"
namespace ftd
{
    template <class T>
    constexpr T&& forward(typename remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<T&&>(t);
    }

    template <class T>
    constexpr T&& forward(typename remove_reference<T>::type&& t) noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<T&&>(t);
    }
}
```

First occasion that uses the forward function:
In List.hpp

```
#include "Utility.h"
namespace fl
{
    namespace containers
    {
        struct NodeBase { /* code... */ };
        /* code... */
        template <class T> struct ListNode : public NodeBase
        {

            /* Code... */
            template <class... Args>
            ListNode(Args&&... args) : m_data(ftd::forward<T>(args)...) {}
            /* Code... */
            T m_data;
        };
    }
}
```

The Error: no template named 'remove_reference'; did you mean 'std::remove_reference'?

Comment: [Compiles fine for me](http://goo.gl/mueJ8J)

Comment: In separate files? @Drew Dormann

Comment: A C++ compiler isn't aware of separate files.  The preprocessor will replace each `#include` statement with the contents of the specified file, producing a single stream of bytes called a "compilation unit".

Comment: Compiles for me using clang-3.5 as well, and I have them in separate files. Which pointed to by Drew, should not be an the issue.

Comment: In the interest of solving your problem, you should post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In an older version of your question, you said you were using clang 3.6.  When your current code [is compiled with clang](http://goo.gl/ihfAmj) it doesn't give the error you show - it correctly complains that `struct NodeBase` can't be a base class without a definition, and `struct Listnode` is missing a semicolon at the end of its definition.

Comment: @DrewDormann But right now I really am staring at the errors. It only happened after I added some code in TypeTraits.hpp but the compiler only complained about the "remove_reference"...I checked again and I am sure that remove_reference class is in the correct namespace, as well as the alias.

Comment: I believe that you're staring at the errors. But you are failing at describing how anyone else can reproduce the same errors. This is still not an MCVE.